# Getting a 400 back when posting to SharePoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, http-400-bad-request

I'm trying to POST a new item to my SharePoint 365 list via Java 6. (I know this is an old version. This is a technology constraint I have to work with.)

First I worked out the url and the body and tried my post in Postman, and that creates a new list item and gets a 201 back as expected. But when I try it in Java I get 400.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
    
try {
    String url = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/yyyy/_api/lists/getbytitle('TaxExemptRecords')/items";
        
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String token = "...";
    
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date d = c.getTime();
            
    sb.setLength(0);
    sb
        .append("{")
        .append("\"Title\"").append(":").append("\"A Test Fax\",")
        .append("\"SenderFax\"").append(":").append("\"8005551212\",")
        .append("\"SenderState\"").append(":").append("\"TN\",")
        .append("\"Received\"").append(":\"").append( sdf.format(d) ).append("\"")
        .append("}");
    String payload = sb.toString();
            
    Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String,String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
    headers.put("X-RequestDigest", "...");
            
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
    ServiceResponse response = client.Post(url, token, headers, payload);
    
    } finally {

    }       
}

public ServiceResponse Post(String url, String token, Map<String,String> headers, String body) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
    try {
        URL urlObj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            
        for(String k:headers.keySet()) {
            connection.setRequestProperty(k, headers.get(k));
        }
            
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
            
        connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                
        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        byte[] input = body.getBytes();
        os.write(input, 0, input.length);           
                
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()) );
        String inputLine;
        sb.setLength(0);
        while ((inputLine = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(inputLine);
        }
        inputReader.close();
        String responseBody = sb.toString();
                
        return new ServiceResponse(responseCode, responseBody); 
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        String stackTrace = Util.ExceptionToString(ioe);
        logger.verbose(stackTrace);
        return null;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        String stackTrace = Util.ExceptionToString(e);
        logger.verbose(stackTrace);
        return null;
    } 
        
}
```

Neither my token nor digest is expired. The stack trace doesn't say much:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/yyyyy/_api/lists/getbytitle('TaxExemptRecords')/items
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor26.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1959)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1954)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:694)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1953)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1523)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1507)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getInputStream(b.java:3)
```

Comment: Try setting your Accept and Content-Type headers to `application/json;odata=nometadata`

Comment: @Rob, Thanks for that suggestion. I tried that, but it made no difference I can see.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your request body missing `__metadata` notation.

You need to do GET from this URL `https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/yyyy/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TaxExemptRecords')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName`

Get the value of `ListItemEntityTypeFullName`, then put it in your request body like below.

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "-------the ListItemEntityTypeFullName value-----"
    },
    "Title": "A Test Fax",
    "SenderFax": "8005551212",
    "SenderState": "TN",
    "Received": "2022-12-31T05:22:00",
}
```

Let me know if it works, as I'm not sure what else is missing. Make sure the date format is also in ISO8601.

Comment: I tried that, it seems to make no difference - not that I can tell by looking a the stack trace anyway. If I log out by headers and payload I get {Accept=application/json;odata=nometadata, X-RequestDigest=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Content-Type=application/json;odata=nometadata}
{"__metadata": {"type": "SP.Data.TaxExemptRecordsListItem"},"Title":"A Test Fax","SenderFax":"8005551212","SenderState":"TN","Received":"2022-34-21 01:34:04"}

Comment: Usually, regardless of the error, the response will still return you with the correct error message in JSON format. Can you try call getResponseMessage() and see what's the return? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseMessage-- By the way, HTTP error 400 can be many things. https://code2care.org/sharepoint/how-to-create-sharepoint-online-list-item-using-rest-api

Comment: The response message is just 'Bad Request'.

Comment: I did correct my date format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss but I still get the bad request. It's odd that there's nothing else in the response.

Comment: What if you use ISO8601 format? It'd be yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, but I will mention that I get an identical exception if I post for a bearer token, which does not include any date. So I doubt it has anything to do with the date. If I do a GET, for example to fetch my list's metadata, that works fine. But every POST blows up.

Comment: I tried swapping out the vanilla java.net stuff for the apache client - an old one of course -- but that just got me a socket reset.

Comment: You are correct, using SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") fixes it. I didn't notice this in Postman because my sample date value did not have any time component. In other words the endpoint will take '2020-01-01' but not '2020-01-01 04:24:45'. Thank you!